# Is there a website to upload performance benchmark results?

Tags: benchmarking

I am looking for a website, where I can upload performance benchmarks results( for example created from passmark ) to be able to monitor changes in performance of my computers.

Answer (score 1):

Openbenchmarking.org is such a website where you can upload benchmark results from  Software and Hardware Tests. You can also build your own web-based reports after registration, downloading+running the benchmarks, and upload.

These are the test suites: https://openbenchmarking.org/suites/pts

You'll see that the test suites are called "[Phoronix Test Suites](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/)" (download here). Why this name? This is because the openbenchmarking.org site is a spin-off of Linux-News Website [phoronix.com](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=home),  and its maintainer, Michael Larabel. He and probably a team of contributors have developed the benchmark suite over many years to post results of his own benchmarks online, and this has turned into an open platform. There are hundreds of benchmarking articles online at phoronix.com, e.g. this one : [NVIDIA/AMD Linux Gaming Performance For Hitman 2 On Steam Play](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=hitman2-steam-linux&num=1).
and on openbenchmarking.org there are [thousands of anonymous benchmark runs](https://openbenchmarking.org/results/latest) from registered users, and their PCs/Laptops.

Comment: its a little bit complicated. for example, i wasnt able to find intel xeon e1505m in the database. I found geekbench in the meanwhile and find it quite good until now.